# jQuery .add() doesn't work as it should

Tags: jquery, arrays, slidetoggle

I need to `.slideToggle()` two div simultaneous.

In order to do it, I used `.add()` to add the elements into array and apply `.slideToggle()` on both of them in the same time.

When I tested my code I figured something works suspiciously.

I went down to the bottom of the problem and I was able to figure that the `.add()` caused the problem - no Idea why.

Anyway, here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fewpb/) so you can see what I am talking about (you need to change the javascript to test both [the right way and the bugged one]).

Generally I can use the working method but I really want to understand why the `.add()` doesn't work as it should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `changeItems` as callback only on one call in the working example.

And you're calling it twice by using `jQuery.add` and then `slideToggle`.